# How is char variable stored in recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverseSentence();
int main() {
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    reverseSentence();
    return 0;
}

void reverseSentence() { //(1)
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c); //input: abc (2)

    if (c != '\n') { (3)
        printf("%c-",c); //output1: a-b-c- (4)
        reverseSentence(); // call reserseSentence (5)
        printf("%c", c); // output2 will return after output1 finish : cba (6)
    }
}
```

**DISPLAY**: a-b-c-cba

In `void` `reverseSentence()` the program will work:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 5 -> 6 ->5 -> 6

Can you explain how it works? 
Why `c` variable can store all value?

Comment: This seems to already contain the answer to the question. A perfect example and explanation. I really do not get what the question is.

Comment: It works using a stack of activation frames for each recursion level.

Comment: The only thing I see is that you have the 5 at entering the recursive call and a leaving it. If you split that into 5a and 5b there should not be any unclarity left.

Comment: To answer the question in the title (in contrast to the one in the body): The char variable is stored in the local variable `c`, which, being a local variable, exists once for each of the recursive calls; more or less from 1 to 6.

Comment: the char variable stored in -- as your name  -- "Stack"

Comment: your question is why c variable can store all value. for every time the function called, the variable will get a new position in stack, how many times calls, how many `c` varilable positions in stack.

Comment: @Barmar you mean ```c``` in ```reverseSentence``` has different address between each call recursion

Comment: @gamesun can you explain why output2 will return 3 time

Comment: @Yunnosch yep, but before the recursive leaving it, the program will ```printf``` all values off ```c```. Why is it not leaving immediately when c == \n ?

Comment: @Stack for reverseSentence called 3 times, as you know, print at (4) 3 times, and every time exit from reverseSentence, the outside code (not exactly expression, but help understand) means the code (6) continue execute, so the (6) executed 3 times too.

Comment: @gamesun I understood that after the recursive calls three times will have three variables stored in The stack. That right?

Comment: @Stack Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems the understanding on how local variables work. I will use a simplified model, where a stack is used for local variables only.

When `main` calls `reverseSentence`, the local variable (`c`) is allocated on the stack:

```
+--------+
|   c    | <------current running copy of reverseSentence
+--------+
| main   |
```

After some statements, `reverseSentence` calls `reverseSentence` again. So a next copy is created on the stack:

```
+--------+
|   c    | <------current running  reverseSentence
+--------+
|   c    | <------previous running reverseSentence
+--------+
| main   |
```

As more and more recursive calls are made, the stack gets a larger number of `c` variables.

When `reverseSentence` returns, the local variables for that running version get destroyed.

```
+--------+
| xxxxxx |  <----- reverseSentence that returned
+--------+
|   c    | <------current running copy of reverseSentence
+--------+
| main   |
```

In reality, the model is a bit more complicated. Depending on the architecture of the processor, the stack may contain return addresses or pointers to contexts etetera. But as a first model on how local variables work, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think pictures will be more clear, the f stand for reverseSentence.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I just learned it at school yesterday, it's Computer Organization and Architecture, but it's a bit confusing to apply it to the C language.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` will eat one character at a time, so each time `reverseSentence()` is recurred it will go to the next on until it hits the newline and then the if test doesn't take and the recursion ends. Since by how recursion works the last instance gets to do the last `printf`, and so you get `cba` on the way out.

In a sense you could consider inputting "abc" as an error: the reason is that as stated the program will only put one character at a time into `c`. This is not a good way of handling user input generally: it'd be better to make it an array into which the entire input string is processed. Introducing recursion into this just makes it messy for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

`char c` is not storing data ,each time it will read one character with `scanf` and print it and then ,because this is a recursive function ,it will first go to last character of your input and print them from first to last.

this program is not reversing the sentence ,since there is no sentence ,it's just reading some character and print them from last one to first one with a recursive function.

but this code takes too long and is not suggested ,instead you can define an string and take it as input then print it from last to first(except `\0`) ,but even this method is not reversing the sentence, both your program and this method are printing from last to first.

Comment: yep, i try to understand how the recursive work! And this i confusing problem with me. Now i can understand how variables can stored. But a little bit is why c==\n (output2 printf c after the recursive leaving it.

Comment: @Stack This is how recursive works .You summon it ,until you reach your base in this case `c==\n`  ,then from last time you called the function ,it will go to your first time. you have called function until `c==\n`, when it happen you will go to last time you called it, means `c` then you will go to one time before calling it `b` and finally you will print `a`(first function calling) and function ends.(maybe with something like factorial recursive function , this method is easier to understand)

Comment: it not depend on where we `printf` `c` (inside `if` or outside) right?  I think i did understand this problem but I'm not sure

Comment: @Stack you can change your code and it still works but this time it will print `\n` besides other chars. also your first `printf` will print one extra `-`(moving second `printf`)

Answer (score 0):

Functions do not use fixed memory locations for their variables. Each time a function is called, it gets new memory locations to use for their variables.

The way most systems implement this is that the entire program has a reserved area of memory called a *stack*. There is a stack pointer (SP) that indicates the current portion of the stack where are using. Whenever a function starts, it changes the SP to point to a new area in the stack. Then it stores all of its local variables in locations relative to the new SP value, such as SP+4, SP+8, SP+24, and so on. When the function is returning, it restores the SP to its previous value.

Thus, the `c` in every call to `reverseSentence` is in a different location.

Most commonly, the stack pointer is started at some high address determined by the operating system and the program loader, and it grows “downward,” meaning that, when a function wants more space on the stack, it subtracts some number from the stack pointer to give a lower address. When the function returns, it reverses that by adding the same number (or by loading the previous stack pointer value from a location where it was saved).